# Replacement for Automapper's ForAllOtherMembers() - scenario 2

Tags: c#, automapper

ForAllOtherMembers extension method was removed from Automapper 11.
We have used it to set a conditional mappings for properties other than the one mentioned before like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<TSource, TDest>()
  .ForMember(d => d.Interval, opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, value) => value != default))
  .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, value) => value != null));
```

How to do this in Automapper 11 ?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1703#issuecomment-250137782